# Where does Chrome store cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Let's say I set a cookie using the `setcookie()` function in `PHP`:

```
setcookie('name','foo',false,'/',false);
```

I can see it in:

```
chrome://settings/cookies
```

However, I can not find the actual file stored on my hard disk. Can anyone tell me where this specific cookie is stored on the hard disk?

Comment: By default, it's a file saved in the path pointed to by the `session.save_path` setting in your php.ini

Comment: Do you wonder where the cookie is stored on the server, or in the browser? Because what you see when using `chrome://settings/cookies ` is the cookies in the browser, which have no idea what cookies could possibly be stored in the server.

Comment: The cookie is on client side no? so i'm wondering where is it stored on the client side on hard disk @JoachimPileborg. I can see other cookies saved on my hard drive by the websites i visited but i can not find the cookie i just created.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/459426/where-does-chrome-store-its-cookie-file. All browsers use similar schemes.

Comment: I already looked it up, I can see other cookies created by other websites on my hard drive but the actual cookie that i created by php as explained above seems missing?!!

Comment: That's exactly where i get confused, cause i'm using the same machine as server and client (using localhost so my machine plays two roles, server and also client), So if i create a cookie, is the cookie get stored on the hard drive of the machine? (cause it's server and also client) if so where? if not how come that i can it on my browser settings?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The answer is due to the fact that Google Chrome uses an SQLite file to save cookies. It resides under:

```
C:\Users\<your_username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network
```

inside `Cookies` file. (which is an SQLite database file)

So it's not a **file** stored on hard drive but **a row** in an SQLite database file which can be read by a third party program such as: `SQLite Database Browser`

EDIT: Thanks to @Chexpir, it is also good to know that the values are stored encrypted.

Comment: It's important to add that the cookie value is stored encrypted.

Comment: Is there any way to view the encrypted Cookies file using SQLite Database Browser?

Comment: No, through SQListe Database Browser. But you can use Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) to do so.

Comment: FYI, in Debian 6 (Squeeze), said Cookie file can be found in `~/.config/chromium/Default`

Comment: Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) is some tool in Windows? If so, can attacker after obtaining file, decrypt it on another computer?

Comment: I've downloaded DB Browser (SQLCipher) from https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/ and on startup the app asks for the encryption key. Does anyone know how to find what Chrome uses ? Without the key you can't delete individual cookies, etc.

Comment: Deleting cookies file won't clean all cookies. Where are the rest of the cookies?

Comment: I was able to read my Cookies file stored at the given location using SQLite Browser, which means that Cookies arent encrypted.

Comment: They have just been moved to the subfolder \Default\Network\Cookies

Comment: The cookies file is now <Chrome user profile directory>\Network\Cookies . See answer by MFKDGAF.

Answer (score 31):

For Google chrome Version 97.0.4692.71 **(Latest Release)** cookies are found inside the Network folder.

There is a file called "Cookies".

Path : C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network

Remember to replace user_name.

Comment: Reference: [https://dfir.blog/cookies-database-moving-in-chrome-96/](https://dfir.blog/cookies-database-moving-in-chrome-96/)

Comment: Note, if the user uses Chrome profiles, then cookies will be stored in `C:\Users\<your_username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile [n]\Network` where [n] is the profile number (1,2,3, etc)

Answer (score 7):

Windows:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\<profile>\Network\Cookies
```

You'll need a program like SQLite Database Browser to read it. However, do not that values are stored with encryption.

macOS:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies
```

Answer (score 3):

On Windows the path now is:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\<profile name>\Network\Cookies
```

Chrome doesn't store each cookie in a separate text file. It stores all of the cookies together in a single SQLite file called `Cookies` in the profile folder as mentioned above. The cookies values are also stored in an encrypted manner and thus not directly readable.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the current browsing path to the Chrome cookies in the address bar is:
chrome://settings/content/cookies

Answer (score 2):

For Google chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 cookies are found inside profile1 folder.

If you browse that you can find variety of information.

There is a separate file called "Cookies". Also the **Cache** folder is inside this folder.

Path :
**C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1**

Remember to replace **user_name**.

For Version 61.0.3163.100
Path :
**C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default**

Inside this folder there is Cookies file and Cache folder.

Comment: "Profile 1" is just a profile directory, for each Chrome profile cookies can be found i its profile directory: "Profile 2", "Profile 3", etc

Comment: If you're on windows, you can just use the environment variable %localappdata% instead of "C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local".

Answer (score 2):

In case you came here to find out how to see info about the cookie of a particular website in Chrome, open Inspector (press F12) navigating the website, go to the tab Application/Aplicativo and look below in the left tree, there is Storage/cookies with all info:

- cookie variables
- content, length
- expiration dates, etc

Answer (score 0):

Since the expiration time is zero (the third argument, the first `false`) the cookie is a *session* cookie, which will expire when the current session ends. (See [the `setcookie` reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)).

Therefore it doesn't *need* to be saved.

Comment: I tried it with `setcookie('name','masoud',time()+3600,'/',false);` ,yet i can not find the cookie file on my hard drive!!

Comment: @varDumper Did you check the browsers [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) cookie database? (Follow my Superuser link in a previous comment)

Comment: Thanks for your time dude, Yes i checked it. I know where chrome stores the cookies. As i mentioned above i can see all other cookies created by other  websites. But the actual cookie that i created by php script seems missing!!

Answer (score 0):

Chromium on Linux: it's an SQLite3 database, located at:

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/Cookies
```

Google Chrome is going to be similar, try replace  with