# Cookies- are the user based or machine based?

Tags: cookies

I am trying to understand more about how cookies work. I would like to know:

Does cookies gets associated with specific user or machine? In another word If I with **User A** use Google Chrome to create a specific cookie, will the cookie be available If I login with User B on the same machine?

Is this something that can be configured (whether to be User based, or Machine based) ?

Comment: Based on this [prior thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021764/where-does-chrome-store-cookies), it's user based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically cookies are browser based(according to you it's machine based). However certain browsers made available to use cookies user based. But there is no any guarantee or W3 standard for it.