# Launch URL from C# and detect when browser is closed

Tags: c#, google-chrome, process

Is there a way to open a webbrowser and detect when the browser is closed through C#?

The basic approach is to use Process.Start and add an event listener to Exited; this works for other programs like Notepad.exe, or for google chrome if it isn't already running. But if Chrome is already running the launched process immediately exits and the URL is opened in the existing chrome. This happens even with the `--new-window` command line argument - it opens in a new window, but not in a new process.

Some googling suggests that the only way to open Chrome in a new process is to specify `--user-data-dir`. This "works" but the first time it's run it asks me to log in in a separate window, and since it's using a different profile, any existing bookmarks/settings will be lost. This is also going to be used in a locked-down environment, so I can't guarantee this will work, and I have no easy way to test this on the real hardware.

I don't truly *need* this to run in a separate process, so long as the C# program can detect when the new window is closed. Running as a separate process would just be one way to do it, but it sounds like that's not an option.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    folder = Path.Combine(folder!, "Chrome");

    var proc = OpenProc("chrome.exe", $"www.google.com --new-window");  //Opens chrome and immediately exits if it's already running.
    //var proc = OpenProc("chrome.exe", $"www.google.com --user-data-dir={folder} --bwsi"); //Works, but causes other problems.
    //var proc = OpenProc("chrome.exe", $"www.google.com --profile-directory=\"Profile 1\"");   //Immediately exits.
    proc!.Exited += Proc_Exited;
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

private static void Proc_Exited(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Proc exited called.");
}
public static Process OpenProc(string browserExe, string args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Open url using {browserExe}, args:  {args}");
    var ps = new ProcessStartInfo(browserExe, args)
    {
        UseShellExecute = true,
        Verb = "open"
    };

    var proc = Process.Start(ps) ?? throw new Exception();
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    return proc;
}
```

Comment: The conventional technique is to [register your app](https://www.meziantou.net/registering-an-application-to-a-uri-scheme-using-net.htm) as a URI handler for a specific URI scheme like `dylanstreb://`, then have the page navigate to that URI after it completes some necessary steps. If you aren't authoring the target page, there is no way without invoking OS API's that track processes or [snooping their cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66272141/1757756). Even then, you'll not be able to verify the page the user is visiting, since browsers don't report this information natively.

Comment: @MavaddatJavid Anything involving the registry is probably not going to work due to the restrictions on the machines. I doubt we can run as admin. Would this apply to actual web pages? This is an existing application that works through a regular web browser on localhost. Right now it starts up and launches the browser, but continues to run after it's closed. I'm being asked to automatically shut down when the browser is closed.

Comment: Ultimately, you or application need to be the author of the destination page so that you can invoke the custom URI schema at the end of whatever tasks the user is expected to complete and have your application handle the completed task. Yes, this applies to both live web pages (served over TCP/IP) or those served locally via localhost. One approach might be to embed the target web page in an `iframe`, but this could raise issues if you're [mixing HTTP and HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site).