# Selenium Python How to use the existing browser's cookies for Login Authentication

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I've a browser(not generated by selenium) which is already logged in to the website.

I need selenium to use the existing cookies so as to not prompt each generated browser for a new login.

here's what i've already tried from what i searched but still can't make it work.

code summary: if the selenium generated browser is already logged in, the browser will close and if it redirected to the login page, it would wait 60 seconds before closing.

```
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import contextlib
import getpass

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


websiteURL = "https://website.alreadylogged.in"
currentUser = getpass.getuser()

chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\" + currentUser + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\"+currentUser+"\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe",options=chromeOptions)

with contextlib.closing(driver) as chromeDriver:    
    chromeOptions.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\" + currentUser + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default") 
    chromeDriver.get(websiteURL)
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, 60) # timeout after 60 seconds
    wait.until(lambda driver: chromeDriver.find_elements_by_class_name('      windows chrome      '))
```

Comment: Using a package like `pickle` can be a good way to dump your current session cookies and read them in again. They are dumped into a local file, so as long as they are still active, new sessions should be able to use them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417335/python-use-cookie-to-login-with-selenium) for an example

Comment: @Brydenr Hi, thank you for answering, but this only saves the cookies generated by selenium, i need the existing ones before the start of the automation.

Comment: You may be able to leverage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021764/where-does-chrome-store-cookies to get the cookies out of Chrome

Comment: Hi @user10888192, I have the exact same need. Did you manage to success to login with existing cookie session?