# How to match the cookie from request header to file

Tags: google-chrome, http, cookies, forms-authentication

I have a local ASP.NET app using Forms authentication.

I'd like to know where this cookie is coming from:

[image]

I looked in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` but have no idea how to work out which file the cookie is stored in.

How can I find out what file the cookie is stored in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, Google Chrome stores cookies in:

C:\Users\Your User Name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies

This is a sqlite database

See:
[Where does Chrome store cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021764/where-does-chrome-store-cookies)
and
[Encrypted cookies in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532870/encrypted-cookies-in-chrome)