# Browser_cookies3 having cookies <CookieJar[]> blank or empty value

Tags: python, cookies

In Browser Cookies3 cookies jar result is blank in python program.

cj = browser_cookie3.chrome(domain_name='www.abc.com')

print(cj)

Please find out the solution of this problem.

Some hints
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021764/where-does-chrome-store-cookies/42514256#42514256](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I Found Some Solution for my above problem.Very Ist please visit Your Website which cookies you want then

userPath=os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%")

GoogleChromeCookies = os.path.join(userPath,"AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Network\Cookies")        #Please Check Cookies Path in C Drive or

#Whatever Drive where you install Google Chrome in you PC or Laptop.

cj = browser_cookie3.chrome(domain_name='www.abc.com',cookie_file=GoogleChromeCookies)

print(cj)